# insert into fails to insert selected data

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-into

I have been working on breaking up a 68GB table into a more normalized structure for the last few weeks, and everything has bee going smoothly until today.

I am attempting to move a select few columns from the big table into the new table with this query:

```
insert into [destination] (col1, col2, col3...)
select col1, col2, col3
From [source]
where companyID = [source].companyID
```

I receive the message, (60113678 row(s) affected), but the data was not inserted into the destination, and the data in the source table hasn't been altered, so what has been affected, and why wasn't any of the data inserted into the destination?

Comment: `but the data was not inserted into the destination` <= how did you verify this?

Comment: `where companyID = [source].companyID` you are trying to join the tables?

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause does nothing at all.  Scope is limited to the `SELECT`, so it can't see the `[destination]` table, which means it can only see the `[source]` table.  As such, the unqualified `companyID` is referenced against `[source]`.  This gives `WHERE [source].companyID = [source].companyID`, which I doubt is that you want to do?  Please could you explain what it SHOULD be doing?  Also, how have you validated that no rows have been inserted?  Please show the full script and results; something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [destination]; INSERT <blah>; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [destination];`

Comment: igor, the destination table has two columns with data and 8 with nulls, all of the nulls are still there and the rows affected is triple the number of rows in the destination.

Comment: MatBailie that is the kind of explanation that I needed. As for what I am trying to accomplish, I am moving specific columns of data into a new table from a table that has over 20 million duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you seem to want to execute is:

```
update d
    set col1 = s.col1,
        col2 = s.col2,
        col3 = s.col3
    from destination d join
         sources s
         on s.companyID = s.companyId;
```

The code you have written is equivalent to:

```
insert into [destination] (col1, col2, col3...)
    select s.col1, s.col2, s.col3
    From [source]
    where s.companyID = s.companyID;
```

The `where` is equivalent to `s.companyID is not null`.  Hence, you have inserted all 60,113,678 rows from `source` into *new* rows in `destination`.

Obviously, one moral of the story is to understand the difference between `insert` and `update`.  More importantly, *qualify* all columns names in a query.  If you had done so, your query would have have failed at `source.CompanyID = destination.CompanyId` -- and you wouldn't have to figure out how to delete 60,113,678 new rows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Might I inquire as to why Update instead of insert?

Comment: @Sluggish1 `where companyID = [source].companyID` mean that you need an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT`

Comment: @Sluggish1 . . . Because you appear to want to change existing rows rather than insert new rows.